# As indicated by this in the constructor

Tags: javascript

Have the following code:

```
function AdminUser(firstName, surName) {
    User.call(this, firstName, surName);

    this.edit = function() {
        alert('test password');
    }
}

function User(firstName, surName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surName = surName;
    this.sayHi = function() {
        alert(this.firstName + ' : ' + this.surName);
    }
}

var user = new User('Василий', 'Пупкин');
var admin = new AdminUser('Иван', 'Горемыко');
```

Here we call User in the context of the this. As indicated by (referenced) this in this case? I understand that a new object is created.

```
User.call(this, firstName, surName);
```

I want to understand what is passed as this in User.call(this)?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: That calls the "parent" constructor.  JavaScript has no concept of "AdminUser extends User".

Comment: @RocketHazmat If this is actually what they're asking, I think it would be a good idea to refer them to ES6 classes, no?

Comment: I agree with @RocketHazmat. Inheritance in JavaScript is not the best right now. When I'm in this situation, I just steal the 'extend' method from a Backbone datatype. So `User.extend = Backbone.Model.extend` and then `AdminUser = User.extend( {} )`;

Comment: @stakolee, Take a look at my answer below, in ES5 you can inherit another classes. You just need to know a bit more about 'Function.prototype' functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way of creating inherited classes is:

```
function User(firstName, surName){
   // Make assigment to properties.
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.surName = surName;
};
// Declare default properties values:
User.prototype.firstName = '';//Set to empty string or whatever you need.
User.prototype.surName = '';//Set to empty string or whatever you need.
//Export functions to prototype.
User.prototype.sayHi = function(){/* Some code */};

function AdminUser(firstName, surName){
    //Call parent class constructor
    User.call(this, firstName, surName);

    //Add addition logic here.
};
//Make prototype inheritance.
AdminUser.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);
AdminUser.prototype.edit = function(){/* Some code */};
```

Now your `AdminUser` inherits from `User` class and you can make check:

```
var au = new AdminUser('Name','SurName');
console.log(au instanceOf User); //true
console.log(au instanceOf AdminUser); //true
```

Comment: You understand me wrong. I'm not interested until that inheritance. I want to understand what this call refers this? In other words, it is transmitted as in this User.call(this)?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov, `User.call(this)` calls function `User` with context set to `this` which in your case is object ob `AdminUser` class instance.

Comment: That is, this object will be admin?

var admin = new AdminUser(); // User.call(this) -> this == admin

Comment: Yeah, this === admin will output `true`

Comment: var admin = new AdminUser(arg1, arg2) startup create the object (admin == {}). Then call User.call(this) and as "this" object will be given admin. Yeah?

Comment: `var admin = new AdminUser(arg1, arg2)` it creates a new instance of AdminUser. In AdminUser function `this` and `admin` is the same object. Then you call function `User` and specify that `this` in function `User` will be set to `this` from function `AdminUser` which currently is object `admin`. If you will create new AdminUser and asign it to `superAdmin` (`var superAdmin = new AdminUser(arg1, arg2)`) then `this` in `AdminUser` will refer to `superAdmin` and `this` in `User` will refer also to `superAdmin`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69156/discussion-between-epsil0ner-and-aleksandr-aleksandrov).

Comment: @Epsil0reR, thank you very much, I realized.